# Normalised and "Normal" Cross Correlation giving different lag positions

Tags: python, cross-correlation, numpy

Using numpy's `np.correlate()` am trying to find the lag position of two data sets of different length.

When I use this operation by its own I find a lag position between my two data sets of 957. However when i implement a normalized cross correlation this changes to a lag of 1126. Can anyone explain why this is the case I would expect them to give the same lag.

My code for finding the lag in the "normal" cross correlation is:

```
corrs = np.correlate(a, b, mode="full") # a and b are pandas DataFrames
lag = (corrs.argmax() - corrs.size/2)
```

For the normalised correlation:

```
a = (a - np.mean(a)) / (np.std(a) * len(a)
b = (b - np.mean(b)) / (np.std(b)

norm_corrs = np.correlate(a, b, mode="full")
lag_norm = (norm_corrs.argmax() - norm_corrs.size/2)
```

In my case i get lag = 9 and lag_norm = 178!

Any pointers would be Great!

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with cross-correlation:

It is difficult to understand the scoring value and both metrics must have the same amplitude : https://anomaly.io/understand-auto-cross-correlation-normalized-shift/ check this out for an example !